# Best Python/Ruby lib for reading text inside images

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, opencv, ocr

Anyone know a library in python/ruby that analize images and extract text inside?

Or a book about image processing ect...

PS: The text is in varius fonts and formats but clear, Tl;Dr: No captcha or similar.

Comment: What does the last line you have written convey ? or is it written by mistake ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OCR for recognising handwriting in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591574/ocr-for-recognising-handwriting-in-net)

Comment: @Angelbit I pointed out one particular duplicate, but this question is really a duplicate of almost any OCR question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, my english is very poor, the text inside images is written in various sizes and formats (bold, italic ect.)

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Have edit, don't have find any question ruby/python specific.

Comment: @Angelbit Ah, the original question didn't mention Python or Ruby.  You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9690752/960195), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11489824/960195), or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9258825/960195) useful, then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use **OpenCV**, an opensource computer vision library and It has Python API. It is considered to be an industry-standard library nowadays.

**OpenCV official site** : http://opencv.org/

If you need some **tutorials on OpenCV-Python**, visit : [opencvpython.blogspot.com](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com)

You can also check this SOF : [Simple Digit Recognition OCR in OpenCV-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python)

In addition to that, OpenCV samples has got some OCR implementations.

But I would recommend you to use **Tesseract for OCR**. It is the best Open source OCR engine, developed by HP, but now handled by Google.

**Tesseract site** : https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Python API of tesseract, **Pytesser** : https://github.com/RobinDavid/Pytesser

Also check this SOF : [How do I choose between Tesseract and OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489824/how-do-i-choose-between-tesseract-and-opencv)

So you can use OpenCV to preprocess the image and use Tesseract for OCR.